# Expandable ListView inside fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, expandablelistview

I have an activity with view pager which contains 5 fragments.In layout of each fragment i need an expandable list view. when the normal listview is used in each fragment the application runs fine but when expandable listview is used application crashes.How to use expandable listview inside a fragment?

Comment: Unless you post your code and proper Logs I doubt anyone can/will help you... For the incomplete question like this, all I can say is, **there has to be some issue with your code. Do fix it** ... So, please post the code and logs if possible.

Comment: What you tried so far ?

Answer (score 0):

Could you offer your crash log? No log, no solution...

The following code will don't crash. `Fragment` inside `Activity`, the rootview of `fragment` is `ExpandableListView`. Maybe it can help you.

```
private Map<String, List<String>> dataset = new HashMap<>();
private String[] parentList = new String[]{"first", "second", "third"};
private List<String> childrenList1 = new ArrayList<>();
private List<String> childrenList2 = new ArrayList<>();
private List<String> childrenList3 = new ArrayList<>();

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_expandable_listview, container, false);
}

private void initialData() {
    childrenList1.add(parentList[0] + "-" + "first");
    childrenList1.add(parentList[0] + "-" + "second");
    childrenList1.add(parentList[0] + "-" + "third");
    childrenList2.add(parentList[1] + "-" + "first");
    childrenList2.add(parentList[1] + "-" + "second");
    childrenList2.add(parentList[1] + "-" + "third");
    childrenList3.add(parentList[2] + "-" + "first");
    childrenList3.add(parentList[2] + "-" + "second");
    childrenList3.add(parentList[2] + "-" + "third");
    dataset.put(parentList[0], childrenList1);
    dataset.put(parentList[1], childrenList2);
    dataset.put(parentList[2], childrenList3);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    initialData();
    ExpandableListView expandableListView = (ExpandableListView) view;
    expandableListView.setAdapter(new MyAdapter());
}

class MyAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {


    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return dataset.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int i) {
        return dataset.get(parentList[i]).size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int i) {
        return dataset.get(parentList[i]);
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int i, int i1) {
        return dataset.get(parentList[i]).get(i1);
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int i, int i1) {
        return i1;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int i, boolean b, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        if (view == null) {
            view = View.inflate(getActivity(), R.layout.parent_item, null);
        }
        view.setTag(R.layout.parent_item, i);
        view.setTag(R.layout.child_item, -1);
        TextView text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.parent_title);
        text.setText(parentList[i]);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int i, int i1, boolean b, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        if (view == null) {
            view = View.inflate(getActivity(), R.layout.child_item, null);
        }
        view.setTag(R.layout.parent_item, i);
        view.setTag(R.layout.child_item, i1);
        TextView text = view.findViewById(R.id.child_title);
        text.setText(dataset.get(parentList[i]).get(i1));
        text.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "点到了内置的textview", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int i, int i1) {
        return false;
    }
}
```